# Problem in testing with withConsecutive()

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a class FillUserPaymentStatisticService with methods:

```
public function fillStatisticForAllTime(): void
    {
        $firstDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->userPaymentsRepository->getTheOldestDate());
        $lastDate = (new \DateTime())->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        while ($firstDate < $lastDate) {
            $this->fillStatistic($firstDate);
            $firstDate->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
        }



private function fillStatistic(\DateTime $day): void
    {
        $dateFrom = $day->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        $dateTo = clone $day;
        $dateTo->setTime(23, 59, 59);

        $statisticAll = $this->userPaymentsRepository
            ->getSummaryStatistic(['dateFrom' => $dateFrom, 'dateTo' => $dateTo, 'onlyPaid' => false]);
        $this->userPaymentsStatisticRepository->insertDailyStatistic($statisticAll, $day, false);

        $statisticOnlyPaid = $this->userPaymentsRepository
            ->getSummaryStatistic(['dateFrom' => $dateFrom, 'dateTo' => $dateTo, 'onlyPaid' => true]);
        $this->userPaymentsStatisticRepository->insertDailyStatistic($statisticOnlyPaid, $day, true);
    }
}
```

And I try write test:

```
public function testFillStatisticForAllTime(): void
{
    $dateFromFirst = (new \DateTime())->sub(new \DateInterval('P2D'))->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $dateToFirst = (new \DateTime())->sub(new \DateInterval('P2D'))->setTime(23, 59, 59);

    $dateFromSecond = (new \DateTime())->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D'))->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $dateToSecond = (new \DateTime())->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D'))->setTime(23, 59, 59);

    $statistic = ['addPeopleFromPlugin' => 10];
    $statisticOnlyPaid = ['addPeopleFromPlugin' => 7];

    $this->userPaymentsRepositoryMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getTheOldestDate')
        ->willReturn($dateFromFirst->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    $this->userPaymentsRepositoryMock->expects($this->exactly(4))
        ->method('getSummaryStatistic')
        ->withConsecutive(
            [['dateFrom' => $dateFromFirst, 'dateTo' => $dateToFirst, 'onlyPaid' => false]],
            [['dateFrom' => $dateFromFirst, 'dateTo' => $dateToFirst, 'onlyPaid' => true]],
            [['dateFrom' => $dateFromSecond, 'dateTo' => $dateToSecond, 'onlyPaid' => false]],
            [['dateFrom' => $dateFromSecond, 'dateTo' => $dateToSecond, 'onlyPaid' => true]],
        )
        ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls($statistic, $statisticOnlyPaid, $statistic, $statisticOnlyPaid);

    $this->userPaymentsStatisticRepositoryMock->expects($this->exactly(4))
        ->method('insertDailyStatistic')
        ->withConsecutive(
            [$statistic, $dateFromFirst, false],
            [$statisticOnlyPaid, $dateFromFirst, true],
            [$statistic, $dateFromSecond, false],
            [$statisticOnlyPaid, $dateFromSecond, true],
        );

    $this->fillUserPaymentStatisticService->fillStatisticForAllTime();
}
```

And i have a fail:

Parameter 0 for invocation #0 App\Repositories\Members\Billing\UserPaymentsRepository::getSummaryStatistic(Array (...)): array does not match expected value.

> Expected: Array (
>       'dateFrom' => 2020-02-05T00:00:00.000000+0000
>       'dateTo' => DateTime Object (...)
>       'onlyPaid' => false ) Actual: Array (
>       'dateFrom' => 2020-02-06T00:00:00.000000+0000
>       'dateTo' => DateTime Object (...)
>       'onlyPaid' => false )

If today 2020-02-07 then first date must be 2020-02-06 and second 2020-02-05, why in test the date is 2020-02-06?

When I change method fillStatisticForAllTime like:

```
 while ($firstDate < $lastDate) {
            $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $firstDate->format('U'));
            $this->fillStatistic($date);
            $firstDate->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
        }
```

its become work correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here is that your variables are mutable [objects (passed by a reference)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

Also, mock assertions are being checked after a test and some of your variables have changed.

**FIX:** Clone any date ("detach" from the original variable) before using it.

```
public function fillStatisticForAllTime(): void
{
    $firstDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->userPaymentsRepository->getTheOldestDate());
    $lastDate  = (new \DateTime())->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    while ($firstDate < $lastDate) {
        $this->fillStatistic(clone $firstDate); // <--------------- clone date
        $firstDate->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
}


private function fillStatistic(\DateTime $day): void
{
    $dateFrom = clone $day; // <----------------------------------- clone date
    $dateFrom->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $dateTo = clone $day;
    $dateTo->setTime(23, 59, 59);

    $statisticAll = $this->userPaymentsRepository
        ->getSummaryStatistic(['dateFrom' => $dateFrom, 'dateTo' => $dateTo, 'onlyPaid' => false]);
    $this->userPaymentsStatisticRepository->insertDailyStatistic($statisticAll, $day, false);

    $statisticOnlyPaid = $this->userPaymentsRepository
        ->getSummaryStatistic(['dateFrom' => $dateFrom, 'dateTo' => $dateTo, 'onlyPaid' => true]);
    $this->userPaymentsStatisticRepository->insertDailyStatistic($statisticOnlyPaid, $day, true);
}
```

Btw, your 2nd approach works because you create a new object ("detact" from the original variable)

To avoid similar bugs in future you may want to use [immutable date objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php).